# Remove "problem" tag

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

People often try to tag with a sentence, so they'll write something like:

`java` `upload` `problem`

...in their tags.

So now there are [56 questions on SO tagged `problem`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/problem), a completely useless tag.

I suggest this tag should be removed from all questions containing it.

When there's a list of banned tags, this should go on it.

(Fighting the urge to tag this question `problem`...)

Comment: I think this question actually needs the problem tag. ;-)

Comment: I like the "problem" tag and I would also like to propose a few more, such as: "asked-on-stack-overflow", "contains-words" and possibly even the "has-a-tag" tag.

Comment: Don't forget the `question` tag.

Comment: NTDLS, a `tautology` tag would pretty much cover the lot, don't you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `warning` - 75 questions
- `issue` - 81 questions
- `error` - 1,792 questions
- `line` - 146 (41 are tagged `command` as well, so that's a different [re-tag request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39718/retag-questions-with-both-command-and-line-tags-command-line))

Comment: Isn't a blacklist supposed to be in the pipeline? It is sorely needed. also see my popular moratorium solution at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36841/allow-10ks-to-merge-tags/36845#36845

Answer (score 4):

Agreed.

The `problem` is, there is a subset of users that have no idea what tags are for.

There's no easy way to fix that `problem`.

Comment: Actually, there is a bit, deleting the tag from all questions will at least prevent it from being suggested, so they will have to type it fully themselves.

Comment: That's just fixing the symptom. It'll just rise up with another word, like 'issue'.

Comment: +1 There are also 1792 questions tagged with `[error]`.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed. There's also the issue of tags like this that have ambiguous meaning.

For example, `[exception]` could refer to a specific problem someone is having, or to a .NET `Exception`-related question. That tag, by the way, is used by 1918 questions (fun times sorting that out!).