# So, we can propose merges on the tag info page. Can we propose batch renames and deletions as well?

Tags: feature-request, tags

Batch renames meaning creating a new tag that doesn't exist and deletions being removing the tag entirely.

Also, if it's not too much trouble, I think that the tag subpages should be improved. The tag wiki should be its own page and the landing page when you click on a tag should have the top 5 questions, 5 newest questions, and basic statistics on it. Or something. I'm not a fan of going right to the page with the latest question with that tag since usually that's not what I want - it's usually the info page, stats page, featured page, or hot page.

Oh, and when I'm a roll...how about a way to discuss the tag on the tag? Where people can talk about merging, renaming, deleting, proper use, etc?

An example of where these features would be useful is dealing with the "requirements" tags. I want to easily propose that `requirements-management`, `requirements-gathering`, `requirements-elaboration`, and `software-requirements` be merged into `requirements-engineering` as all questions in the first 3 and it appears some or most of the questions in the 4th are all about requirements engineering. Since StackOverflow is more programming related than software engineering, it would be best to use a broader term here - there's no need for the granularity in topics such as requirements engineering that you would need on a stack exchange dedicated to software engineering. And since this is a huge undertaking (relatively speaking - several tags are being affected), it would be nice to have a place to discuss this other than on meta so that people who follow or participate heavily in these tags can find out that "hey, people want to do things to these tags".

Answer (score 3):

Batch renames / deletions are potentially *very* destructive. I don't think they should be automated - the current system (propose on Meta, wait for consensus and a moderator) seems safer.

> The tag wiki should be its own page and the landing page when you click on a tag should have the top 5 questions, 5 newest questions, and basic statistics on it.

I like this part of the suggestion. I would like to see a tag "home" dashboard with,

- Wiki excerpt
- Recent questions
- Recent *answers*
- Top questions
- Top answers
- Asker / answerer leaderboard (subset of what's on the Stats page, just the top names)
- Recent discussions (from the chat system, when that's done)

So... -1 for the first paragraph, +1 for the second.

Comment: They shouldn't be automated, you are right. But there should be a way to vote so the mods who actually do it can see what the most popular requests are and then decide if the users are right (which I would assume they would be most of the time) and then do it.

Comment: @Thomas: [here's what I wrote the *last* time something like this was proposed...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36841/allow-10ks-to-merge-tags/36843#36843)

Comment: See, we shouldn't really have to come to meta for these discussions. It should be built into the engine of the site so discussion happens there. I think it makes a lot more sense.

Comment: ^ That would be paragraph 3, btw. :)