# Please blacklist the [problem] tag ... again

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-block-request

[problem](/questions/tagged/problem) is back, and it shouldn't be.

It's been burninated [at](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36109/remove-problem-tag) [least](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79037/tag-removal-request-problem-and-problems) [three](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77059/tag-ban-request-problem-and-problems) times, and that last one was supposed to be a blacklist.

Please murder it once and for all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm, I don't actually see this blacklisted anywhere. Not sure what happened there; I'll try again.

Comment: A more interesting question is, how did it get back in the first place? All those questions were created by users with < 1500 rep, so how were they able to tag them with `[problem]`?

Comment: I suspect a migrated question, but meh, it wasn't blacklisted and should have been

Comment: It works now.


sorry, the 'problem' tag is not allowed.